# how I can put asp tag to webpage from database?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I create tab with bootstrap and asp.net 
here I have 2 tabs like bellow :

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class=""><asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="#home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">tab1</asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li class=""><asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">tab2</asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul>
```

I want read tabs name from DB , maby I have 5 tabs instead of 2 tabs 
How I can generate

and  tags and put into the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use asp:Repeater such as this

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="CountryTabs">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li class="">
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="#home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><%#Container.DataItem("title")%></asp:HyperLink>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```